# Flatlist not showing each objects elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Trying to show a flatlist with data from firestore but for some reason the {item.title} that is supposed to be shown is not. The yellow touchable opacity is being shown just fine and it's being called the right amount of times (3 objects in posts array, 3 yellow boxes) Heres the code:

getting data:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const discoverList = firestore()
    .collection('Public')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const goals = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
        goals.push({
          ...documentSnapshot.data(),
          key: documentSnapshot.id,
        });
      });
      setPosts(goals);
      setLoading(false);
    });

  return () => discoverList();
}, []);
```

posts hook:
`const [posts, setPosts] = useState()`

flatlist return:

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 20, marginHorizontal: 20, flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.searchPos}>
          <Text style={styles.pageTitle}>Discover new goals</Text>
          <SearchBar />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.fl}>
          <FlatList
            data={posts}
            renderItem={(item) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => console.log(posts)}
                style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', marginVertical: 20 }}
              >
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{item.title}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

I have the touchable opacity printing out the posts array for the sake of debugging and this is what is being printed.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "description": "this is the body text",
    "key": "8x9RPFqKlyXdwyTQMQqJ",
    "title": "title here",
    "topic": "Public",
  },
  Object {
    "key": "DaFVjEUBDrVXDCSsiotr",

  },
  Object {
    "description": "Eek",
    "key": "n1YAuqv4gaZ2EFDwbCQD",
    "title": "Eem",
    "topic": "Public",
  },
]
```

All help is appreciated, Thank you!

Edit:

```
Object {
  "index": 2,
  "item": Object {
    "description": "Eek",
    "key": "n1YAuqv4gaZ2EFDwbCQD",
    "length": 1,
    "title": "Eem",
    "topic": "Public",
  },
  "separators": Object {
    "highlight": [Function highlight],
    "unhighlight": [Function unhighlight],
    "updateProps": [Function updateProps],
  },
}
```

Comment: could be something related to font styles, try changing font color and size

Comment: also, it'd be better to rename `discoverList` to `unsubscribeDiscoverList`, it looks like you're fetching results when unmounting

Comment: no luck with that, unfortunately...

Comment: what does it log if you add a console.log in renderItem? `(item) => { console.log(item); return <TouchableOpacity ...`

Comment: check the edit, for some reason, it was returning the entire object, I did item.item.title, and that fixed things. Thanks for the guidance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling in the future:

building off of what Drew and diedu said, was trying to return the entire object, where .title doesn't exist.

This change fixed my issue:

```
                    <FlatList
                        data={posts}
                        renderItem={(item) => <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(posts)} style={{ backgroundColor: '#ECECEC', marginVertical: 20, height: 100, borderRadius: 10 }}>
                            <Text >{item.item.title}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>}
                    />
```

check to see what the item is actually trying to display as deidu suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to get inside the `Array` so it should just be

```
[
  Object {
    "description": "this is the body text",
    "key": "8x9RPFqKlyXdwyTQMQqJ",
    "title": "title here",
    "topic": "Public",
  },
  Object {
    "key": "DaFVjEUBDrVXDCSsiotr",

  },
  Object {
    "description": "Eek",
    "key": "n1YAuqv4gaZ2EFDwbCQD",
    "title": "Eem",
    "topic": "Public",
  },
]
```

Comment: How would you do that? tried posts.data but that wasn't it

Answer (score 0):

Check FlatList document: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem

Takes an item from data and renders it into the list.
Get the `{item}` field from `data` for rendering instead of directly using `data` as item for rendering,

try with follow code:

```js
          <FlatList
            data={posts}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => console.log(posts)}
                style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', marginVertical: 20 }}
              >
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{item.title}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          />
```